# unable to locate package hostpad

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I want to use Ubuntu as wifi router and the solution I found was hostpad. But I am unable to install it, it says, unable to locate package hostpad.  What is the possible solution here? Thanks

Comment: Is the package actually named hostapd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no package `hostpad`, thats right. The package name is `hostapd`, a user space IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator.

Therefore

```
sudo apt-get install hostapd
```

The package is in the <kbd>universe</kbd> repositories. Check your configuration via <kbd>Software & Updates</kbd>. Select the right entry and select <kbd>Main server</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks, it was a mistake, but still it is showing  Package hostapd is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'hostapd' has no installation candidate

Comment: What's your Ubuntu version

Comment: The version is Ubuntu 14.04.2

Comment: Check your repositories, I have updated my answer.